# Use PhantomJs, Nodejs and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, dom, xpath, phantomjs

Is there a way to use PhantomJS to scrape the data then parse the results with nodejs XPath and DOM then save into MySQL?

I've installed both PhantomJS core and also PhantomJS Node module but trying to run Node from shell level to execute the scraper then set up cronjobs to run them in scheduled basis.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, there are [modules that integrate Phantom.JS with Node.js](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). I think you may need to ask a more specific question if you need a more specific answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried various bridges between node and PhantomJS and ended up writing another bridge ;). It's called [phridge](https://github.com/peerigon/phridge) and provides a way to pass functions to PhantomJS and return results back to node:

```
// node
phantom.run("h1", function (selector, resolve) {
    // this code runs inside PhantomJS

    phantom.addCookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", "localhost");

    var page = webpage.create();
    page.customHeaders = {
        Referer: "http://google.com"
    };
    page.settings = {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)"
    };
    page.open("http://www.google.com", function () {
        var text = page.evaluate(function (selector) {
            return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
        }, selector);

        // resolve the promise and pass 'text' back to node 
        resolve(text);
    });
}).then(function (text) {
    // inside node again
    console.log("The element contains the following text: "+ text);
});
```